# Matrix Multiplication by adding another number for the hell of it?

Tags: matrices

I want to multiply a 4x4 by a 3x1. Can I just add a 1 to the bottom of the 3x1 to make this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Sure. Though personally, if you're going to add arbitrary numbers to your matrix, I'd go for 42. The question, of course, is why the *hell* would you want to do that in the first place. You'll need to explain your motivation a great deal better if you expect a sensible answer...

Comment: I want to add a vector in $21313$-dimensions with a vector in $13287489791$-dimensions. Could I just adjoin $13287468478$ random entries to the first vector in order to make it possible? Yes...it WORKS, but does it really have any relevance to the situation? No...

Comment: @fretty wow did you do that subtraction in your head? :) Impressive.

Comment: Ahhh it wasn't that hard ;)

Comment: Answers and comments are a bit harsh, but you must understand that your question, as it is, is impossible to answer. We define operations to model useful/intersting concepts. Matrix multiplication is not just some out-of-thin-air way to combine entries. Sometimes we indeed add some seemingly arbitrary "missing entry"(e.g. homogenous coordinates, used widely in 3d graphics), but we still do this for some purpose. We don't know if adding 1 to the bottom will give you the result you need (my interpretation of "can I?"), since we don't know what is it that you need.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś Yes, this question relates to computer graphics. In my notes, a 3x1 just has an added '1' to make the multiplication work. The only thing is, there's no reasoning given for this manipulation. So, in terms of computer graphics, adding a '1' is acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting $1$ at the bottom doesn't seem to make a lot of sense to me.
You can of course do it if you want, but it's probably not going to give you any useful result.

On the other hand, it would make a bit more sense to add a $0$ to the bottom.  This makes sense because you can view an $m \times n$ matrix as having entries of $0$ outside its $m \times n$ domain, and with this definition matrix multiplication and addition all work the same.  In this sense you can even talk about the space of *all* matrices, in which a "matrix" is an infinite 2-dimensional grid of real numbers, such that all but finitely many of those numbers is $0$.

Of course, there is no identity matrix in this space.  Perhaps we should allow for infinite nonzero entries as long as there are only finitely many in each row or column.  That way the infinite matrix with $1$s along the diagonal is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

No, because you could also equivalently add a "$2$" to the bottom of the $3\times 1$, or you could add a $3$ etc..

This is bad because there would be no unique representation of the element produced, and if you want to consider the space of these various "$3\times 1$" elements, there would not be a unique additive identity, or unique absorbing element.

Example:

you could have both $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
1 \end{array} \right]$ and  $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
2\end{array} \right]$ and $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
3\end{array} \right]$ but then we must have:

$0=A-A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
2\end{array} \right]$ and $0=A-A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
1\end{array} \right]$ so the additive and absorbigng element is no longer unique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think Goos' is what I want to be correct! I hope he/she is!

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin
If you know about equivalence relations, the set you are looking at can be well defined by defining $A$~$B$ $\iff$ $a_1=b_1,a_2=b_2,a_3=b_3$, then we consider the set $X$ of all element of the form:
$A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 \\
a_2\\
a_3  \\
\alpha \end{array} \right]$ where $\alpha\in\Bbb R$

then the well defined set you want is $X/$~$\,\,\,\,\,$